# First column with NULL value in a table

Tags: sql

I would like to get to know how I can get the first column with NULL value from the left for each row in my table, I've tried with `SELECT CASE` but it doesn't work the way I would like.

Guys, I'd like to be crystal-clear about what I want to accomplish. I have a table with 22 columns and there are rows in which last 10 columns have NULL values but I need to get to know only a name of the first column from the left with NULL value.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Please provide existing code sample that didn't work for you. And name of RDBMS you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You get the *value* from the first non-NULL column using `coalesce()`:

```
select coalesce(col1, col2, col3, . . .)
```

You can get the name using `case` logic:

```
select (case when col1 is not null then 'col1'
             when col2 is not null then 'col2'
             . . .
        end)
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be is null and not is not null?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't think so, because you want to know the first column that has a null. The value in a case statement or coalesce would not tell you which column was null.

Answer (score 0):

Just specify `NULL` as your first field selection.

```
SELECT NULL, FieldA, FieldB, FieldC etc
FROM yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

The only general approach here is case statement:

```
Case
when col1 is null then 'col1'
when col2 is null then 'col2'
when col3 is null then 'col3'
end as frst_null
```

This way frst_null would contain the name of the first column containing Null value. You can order columns whichever order you like.